# Prevent interval being queued on multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created simple script with setInterval function and it is working fine on **first** button click, but if I click my button couple of times my interval is **queued up**! I have tried to solve this using **one** function with Jquery but then I cannot set my Intereval again. 
Is there a way to prevent this? Thank you!!

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/K7pEG/)

My code:

```
 var changeClass=function(){

   if($('ul li.active').length==0){
   $('ul li:first').addClass('active');
   }
    else if($('.active').next().length==0){
       $('.active').removeClass('active');
       $('ul li:first').addClass('active');
    }
      else{
      $('.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active')
      }

 } 

$(document).ready(function() {
 var intervalID;
    $(".button").click(function(){
    intervalID=setInterval(changeClass,1000);
    });

      $(".clear").click(function(){
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what are you actually trying to do? If you want the start button to be ignored when the interval is already set, write your click handler like this:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    if(!intervalID) {
        intervalID = setInterval(changeClass,1000);
    }
});
```

If you want the start button to *restart* the interval then you can issue a click on the clear button every time the start button is clicked like this:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    // Perform a click on the clear button
    $(".clear").click();

    intervalID = setInterval(changeClass,1000);
});

$(".clear").click(function(){
    clearInterval(intervalID);
});
```